# How to generate a Xamarin IPA file

Tags: ios, xamarin

Might be a simple question but I'm struggling to get the IPA file for iOS devices. I've read that I need an account at Apple Developer Program. I don't want to publish the app to the App store. I've also read that I need to use Ad-Hoc to build the IPA file that I don't need to publish. Can someone maybe just clarify for me I'm a bit lost.

The apk builds and runs without a problem

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.9.2

MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3 virtual Machine.

xCode Version 12.4

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use the Archive functionality in Visual Studio for Mac to create said IPA. However, you need a developer account to create the distribution and provisioning profiles for signing it.

Comment: Without the distribution and provisioning profiles the app won't work?

Comment: Without them you cannot sign the package and distribute it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Certification**

> Certification of computer development
> qualifications, each developer account has a set, divided into two
> types:

1. Developer Certification

> installed on the computer to provide permissions: the developer was able to test the app
> on a real machine. A copy can be generated for
> installation on multiple computers;

2. Distribution Certification

> Distribution Certification is installed on the computer to provide the
> permission to publish iOS programs: developers can make test versions
> and release versions of programs. Copy is not allowed, only the
> computer equipped with the certificate can be used; (the copy is
> introduced in the Keychain below)

**Provisioning Profile**

> Authorization file is the authorization for devices such as iPod
> Touch, iPad, iPhone. What is recorded is the UDID of the device and the
> App Id of the program. Only the authorized device can install or
> debug the program corresponding to the Bundle identifier(App Id) and the App
> Id recorded in the authorization file. Developer account will select
> App Id when creating authorization file, (add in App Id under
> developer account, single choice) and UDID (add up to 100 in Devices
> under developer account, multiple choice).

There are two types of authorization files, corresponding to the corresponding certificates:

1. Developer Provisioning Profile (development authorization file)

> Is used on a computer with a development certificate or a copy, and
> the developer selects the authorization file to install the program to
> the authorization file record through the computer In the device, then you
> can test on the real machine. Note: Ensure that the computer has
> permission to debug on the real machine, that is, install the
> development certificate or copy; the Bundle identifier of the program
> in the development tool must be the same as the App Id of the selected
> authorization file; the UDID of the device connected and debugged is
> in the selected authorization file There are records.

2. The Distribution Provisioning Profile (release authorization file)

> Is used to make the test version and the release version of the
> program on the computer with the distribution certificate (that is,
> the computer with the configuration certificate, there is only one).
> The release version is the program file published on the App Store.
> When the developer account creates the authorization file, select the
> store option and select the App Id without selecting the UDID; the
> beta version is the program file that can be synced to the device by
> the tester before the release. When the developer account creates the
> authorization file, select AdHoc, select App Id and UDID; only the
> device corresponding to the selected UDID can install the program made
> by the authorization file.

**The Keychain** (development key)

> Will generate a Keychain under the certificate when the certificate is
> successfully installed. The certificate copy mentioned above is to
> export the Keychain (that is, the .p12 file) through the computer that
> configures the certificate and install it on other computers so that
> other computers can get it. Permission corresponding to the
> certificate. Developer Certification can make a copy of Keychain and
> distribute it to other computers for installation so that it can be
> tested on the real machine. Note: Distribution Certification can only
> be used by the computer with the certificate. Therefore, even if the
> exported Keychain is installed on other computers, other computers may
> not have the authority of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an Apple developer account for that.